# Using different images in anchor tags (link, visited, etc)

Tags: css

I'm trying to get different images to show up for different states of an anchor tag but I can't get it to work. Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Here's the image => won't let me post images but it's 480x30 pixels

Here's the CSS;

```
a.image {
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color:white;
display:inline-block;
width:160px;
height:30px;
margin-left:-12px;
margin-top:16px;
padding-top:6px;
text-align:center;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:none;
}

a.image:link {
background-image:url('images/buttons.png');
background-position:0px 320px;
}

a.image:visited {
background-image:url('images/buttons.png');
background-position:0px 0px;
}

a.image:active {
background-image:url('images/buttons.png');
background-position:0px 160px;
}
```

Here's the HTML;

```
<a href='ifp.asp?width=1512&ProjectGroupID=&ProductID=536&model=Addison 536&plan=Lower Level Plan' class='image'>Lower Level Plan</a>
```

I currently get only "Lower Level Plan" in white text. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "lower level"?

Comment: The `background-position` property is defined as `Xpos Ypos`.  Are you sure that you shouldn't be reversing the order of your values?

Answer (score 1):

You are changing your background-positions on the y-axis when you should be changing them on the X-axis if your sprite is 480 W x 30 H. You should also be using -X dimensions to indicate the sprite needs to be shifted in the negative direction (to the left) So you can rewrite like this:

```
a.image:link {
background-position:-320px 0px;
}

a.image:visited {
background-position:0px 0px;
}

a.image:active {
background-position:-160px 0px;
}
```

Note that I also removed the background-image declaration here, as you can simply move this up into the a.image style block.

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested and I still can't get it working. I added another line with in-line style and this button does show up but not the other button. Here is the line that does work;    <a class='image' style="background-image:url('images/buttons.png'); background-position:-320px 0px;" onClick="reset();">Reset</a>

Comment: Where is the image located relative to the CSS in the directory structure?  Is it in an images subdirectory of the directory the CSS is in? If using a relative URL reference in a CSS file.  The path is relative to the location of the CSS file.

Comment: CSS and images are both sub-directories of where the program is located. I changed it to this, background-image: url('../images/buttons.png');, but still no luck.

Comment: How about using full path reference like `url(/path/to/images/buttons.png)`?

Comment: I changed the url to an absolute path and it's somewhat working but not quite. I'll try three separate images.

Comment: Using a full path and three separate images got the job done. Thanks for your help!